# A question on integral notations

Tags: integration, expected-value

Good day!

I just would like to ask some notations involved in integration.
Specifically, given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, F_t, \{F_t\}, P )$

$$\displaystyle E\bigg[\int_0^t f(s-)dA(s)\bigg] $$
Where $A$ is an increasing mapping.

Im confuse what is the meaning of $f(s-)dA$.
This maybe is basic but I’m new i really dont understand the meaning of such. Any help is highly appreciated or any references where this concepts are being discussed.

Comment: $f(s-)$ is the limit of $f(t)$ as $t$ increases to $s$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for the insight, but i forgot to add t here considered is fixed.

Comment: I meant to say  $f(s−)$
is the limit of $f(u)$ as $u$ increases to s. This is a basic Calculus notation. Nothing to do with Probability Theory.

Comment: To sum it up,  is it something like this?   $$E[\int_0^t f(s-) dA(s)] = E[\int_0^t (\lim_{u\to s^-} f(u) ) dA(s)$$

Comment: I do understand what you mean now, thank you,,,   I’m sorry for this stupid question.